# JWT access token for auth_header in Bot Framework

Tags: jwt, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a MS Teams bot designed to send messages in response to events. For instance, when the bot receives an API message from an external source, it processes the information and sends a corresponding message. The bot is not intended to reply to messages; it's solely for notifications. I began with a Python sample, specifically [02.echo-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/02.echo-bot).  When sending a message to the bot via MS Teams, the message includes a Bearer Token, which can be viewed in `app.py`:

```
# Listen for incoming requests on /api/messages
async def messages(req: Request) -> Response:
    # Main bot message handler.

    if "application/json" in req.headers["Content-Type"]:
        body = await req.json()
    else:
        return Response(status=HTTPStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE)

    activity = Activity().deserialize(body)

    auth_header = req.headers["Authorization"] if "Authorization" in req.headers else ""

    print("auth_header: ", auth_header)

    response = await ADAPTER.process_activity(activity, auth_header, BOT.on_turn)

    if response:
        return json_response(data=response.body, status=response.status)
    return Response(status=HTTPStatus.OK)
```

I'm printing `auth_header` to view the value of the token:

> auth_header:  Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...

After obtaining this token and reconstructing the API post, I'm sending a post request to retrieve a message from a bot without initiating one on MS Teams conversation. The request body looks like this:

```
{
    "conversation": {
        "id": "<CONVERSATION ID>"

    },
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/",
    "text": "bot",
    "status": "stopped",
    "type": "message"
}
```

The problem is that the token expires, and I want to obtain it in a way other than sending a message because the bot's purpose is solely to send notifications.
I followed the instructions for [Authentication with the Bot Connector API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant#emulator-to-bot) but it consistently returns:

> botbuilder.schema._models_py3.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

Comment: This error typically occurs when there is an issue with the bot's authentication setup. Check the bot's app ID and password in the bot configuration file and ensure they match with what's in the Bot Framework portal. Also, verify that the correct Microsoft App ID and Microsoft App Password are being used in your bot's settings. If you are using an .env file to store these values, ensure that they are correctly referenced in your bot's code. If the issue persists, try regenerating the app password in the Azure portal and updating it in your bot's configuration.